# Understanding C++ struct with explicit and default values

Tags: c++, struct

I have a hard time understanding the following code, can someone please elaborate.

```
struct WUpdate {
    explicit WUpdate(std::string id = "", std::string message = "")
        : id(std::move(id)), message(std::move(message)) {}
    explicit WUpdate(const UpgradeJob& job)
        : id(job.m.id), message(job.message) {}

    std::string id;
    std::string message;
};
```

I want to update the above struct to accept a new field as well (called `time` below) with default value `-1`.
I have updated the code above as follows:

```
struct WUpdate {
    explicit WUpdate(std::string id = "", std::string message = "", int time = -1)
        : id(std::move(id)), message(std::move(message)) {}
    explicit WUpdate(const UpgradeJob& job)
        : id(job.m.id), message(job.message) {}

    std::string id;
    std::string message;
    int time{-1};
};
```

the code compiles but when running I can see that the value of `time` is always set to `-1`, regardless of what I try to initialise it with.
I am also getting warning saying that warning: `unused parameter ‘time’` pointing to the second line of updated code.

Comment: You didn't initialize it in the constructor. It has nothing to do with the explicit keyword. The warning says it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the code compiles but when running I can see that the value of `time` is always set to -1, regardless of what I try to initialise it with.

None of the `explicit` keyword or that *default value thing* you mentioned has anything to do with `time` being always set to `-1`.
You simply forgot to initialize `time` in the constructor as follows:

```
struct WUpdate {
    explicit WUpdate(std::string id = "", std::string message = "", int time = -1)
        : id(std::move(id)), message(std::move(message)), 
          time(time) /* <- Here */
    { }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: thanks, I saw it after a while, by the way, what is that called, initialisation in parentheses?

Comment: @theAlse It's called **member initializer lists**